# pynotify in python script go wrong when running with sudo in KDE

Tags: python, pynotify

I just want to show notification in KDE environment.So i tried
pynotifytest.py

```
from pynotify import *
init("test")
Notification("test", "test").show()
```

then i run `sudo python pynotifytest.py`，the error i got was:

```
No protocol specified
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
 ----> 3 Notification("test", "test").show()

Error: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=cb94cb23372d0aff09ce7d8a000024b4 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: No protocol specified\nAutolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

then i tried to drop privilege
pynotifytest.py

```
import os
os.setuid(1000)
from pynotify import *
init("test")
Notification("test", "test").show()
```

still i got the same error only in KDE.In gnome-shell and awesome the notification show up as expected.I have a python program must running with root privilege so i can't leave sudo behind. 1000 is my user's uid logging in X.

My linux distribution is Arch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"it works for me" -- please give more details of your system. It worked on a fedora 15 with SELinux disabled here. Also note that the problem you are getting is on the GTK+ part - not pynotify per se.

Also - does your user "1000" is the one logged in the graphical environment?  Of course this won't work if you are trying to diaplay windows with a user other than the one logged in or root itself.

Comment: sorry for that. I've updated. my uid is 1000 and i'm logged in x.My env is KDE, i've test the script in gnome and awesome, no error occured.

Answer (score 0):

To allow sudo to start graphical application in X, you need to add:

```
Defaults env_keep += "HOME"
```

to visudo.